# echarts use second x axis in tooltip

Tags: javascript, echarts

I have a chart using echarts that has nested x-axis (2 levels).

For the tooltip I want to show both values of the x-axis, but I cannot figure out how to show the respective value of the second x-axis.
I use this function as a formatter in the tooltip:

```
formatter: function(params) {
  console.log(params); // for debugging only
  var tooltip = params[0].name + '<br>';  
  for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {  
    tooltip += params[i].marker + params[i].seriesName + ': ' + params[i].value.toFixed(2) + '<br>';  
  }  
  return tooltip;  
}
```

which results in this tooltip (note that the second X axis corresponding to the age group 'Teen' is missing).

[image]

What I want to have is something like this

[image]

See also [echarts demo](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar1&code=G4QwTgBAJiAuIQLwQNoQgWAFDoN7QHsBbASwDsQzYAJSqALggHIAlEgcwAtYmAaCEOwCmjJgBUhQsnwigANgFcREALJxOAOjB1iACgCU_YWShCwogGJCiIOUKYQAvv0w4I-KMXKUadUWy4efkFlJgBBKAU5INlbJUY1WE1tEz1DCGNTc2YrGzsHZ3RsPEJSCipaE38ObhkQ_yFYEjAhKBl5eNV1LR0iAyMpLMtrW3snF2L3Uu8Kv2YAGSEAMxj65gkpdrjlROTe_ozBs2G8scLXEs8yn0qGBeXV4VEIqJiOne6Uq4PM45yR_LjIpuDxecq-Kr3FZ1J7MFiNZqtLaKD5JHqpPrpX7ZJi5UYFFwXKZXGYQu6sGqPUIbaT8d4JT77LFHHFqQHnSag66zSEUwIw0IvaLIzq7dHfZkmP5MNlnCYg6bg27VfnBWGsBEtNp07YMtFfNIDKWs_FAolc0nKqFU0Q0kWovYYn4s0SygnAy5gm5zJiLaFqwWRYU6lF6x0So1DZhus2cxXe3l-m1wzVIkOixlOyVRmWmjlYAC6AG5sNgCAAHJoEMhIdyTJqwOyMXCTdCwIQAD1glhAAGshBAAGrbADOECWBEgABEvVQILcBCYIGFhHxJs56wQCNESOXm62ILAwBxhDiQB2SCO1250BOwDZYO3sksFGQAMZVsi6cvgEBEEf6HWN7oBAb7ViO25CBocgEOw36_v--hFhAAD0KHjpO0BCAARgo7DsOQ7AQNWcgAJ4HugoCQLAW47uWtY_to_4oAADAWGgUEQA4ANTMAAPNhYAAHxMMhRIgRhkC6FREAkLWLHIXJfEQIxf4jtBUjsEkincdxgH4OJEmHrRTT0dxyCqcxJDsTYYD9pAvGWSOKDWRoI5mCQQgjgAcn-PHMKIECOQhzmue8Gg0RYJAdq0ugAEyAbxTACcJokekZjjpRJLSwAoYA1jR26mWJB6OOuvCTHYmT7sBMDwIwKC4gC9j8AARLKrUFuVkwdmEF4jg1B4GRRh6keWoRvnAQjsJOpEyIZ6B1SADV8rU_C-g8MirTEG3-nClJbUmTAFvKRkCP18wgNhQhyM2WVGeQT7yIwLGnWdEBgAQ8Dti9b0Sfm_1_VMC2jeNoiTe2M1gHNQOLXAy2oOIki0swQo7fCTRasdsPnZel3XbdwMjegj1mM9ECvfd2VfVNv1U7GwHoOWBAjiQn6iNhX00UQ80jQQSxLO53YQAAzJThkbm4J2TKRfWXoNwEtozoOhO8TClZM0tuO5x5eQrElK2dnGhHi-QVcrsBjaE2HgNeZ1LYwS0aEsJDRGYugvu-n66Gz1j6TleU1r7RAaNiSCIMgTWnKJjj6BoNjlh7r4fiQ1Y--2RD-40geyRnGjvEWselebBsjcbrr4iXRmW2DzA22AdtGQ7cPwM7rtPknXup1-wdZ7l-W59YocsuHkduoXccJ53Kdp737gBwPwf59sE8a1L2COEWQA)

```
var data = [  
  { dominantHand: 'Right', age: 'Teen', value: Math.random(), gender: 'Female' },  
  { dominantHand: 'Right', age: 'Adult', value: Math.random(), gender: 'Female' },  
  { dominantHand: 'Right', age: 'Retired', value: Math.random(), gender: 'Female' },  
  { dominantHand: 'Left', age: 'Teen', value: Math.random(), gender: 'Female' },  
  { dominantHand: 'Left', age: 'Adult', value: Math.random(), gender: 'Female' },  
  { dominantHand: 'Left', age: 'Retired', value: Math.random(), gender: 'Female' },   
  { dominantHand: 'Right', age: 'Teen', value: Math.random(), gender: 'Male' },  
  { dominantHand: 'Right', age: 'Adult', value: Math.random(), gender: 'Male' },  
  { dominantHand: 'Right', age: 'Retired', value: Math.random(), gender: 'Male' },  
  { dominantHand: 'Left', age: 'Teen', value: Math.random(), gender: 'Male' },  
  { dominantHand: 'Left', age: 'Adult', value: Math.random(), gender: 'Male' },  
  { dominantHand: 'Left', age: 'Retired', value: Math.random(), gender: 'Male' },  
];

option = {
  title: {
    text: 'Fake Values for Dominant Hand and Age',
  },
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    formatter: function(params) {
      console.log(params); // for debugging only
      var tooltip = params[0].name + '<br>';  
      for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {  
        tooltip += params[i].marker + params[i].seriesName + ': ' + params[i].value.toFixed(2) + '<br>';  
      }  
      return tooltip;  
    }
  },
  legend: {
    data: ['Female', "Male"]
  },
  xAxis: [
    {  
      type: 'category',  
      data: ['Right', 'Left', 'Right', 'Left', 'Right', 'Left'],  
      axisLabel: {  
        interval: 0,  
        rotate: 0,  
      },  
    },  
    {  
      type: 'category',  
      data: ['Teen', 'Adult', 'Retired'],  
      axisLabel: {  
        interval: 0,  
        rotate: 0,  
      },  
      position: 'bottom',  
      offset: 30,  
    },
  ],
  yAxis: [
    {
      type: 'value'
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Female',
      type: 'bar',
      data: data.filter(function(item) {return item.gender === 'Female';}).map(function(item) {return item.value;})
    },
    {
      name: 'Male',
      type: 'bar',
      data:  data.filter(function(item) {return item.gender === 'Male';}).map(function(item) {return item.value;})
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I used the following trick/hack, which creates a map that connects the values of the data to the second axis. To do this, I did the following.

Make sure that each value is unique (I do this by grouping the values and adding a very small unique value to it. Eg if we have two values 0.12345678, I would choose I want my data to be precise to 8 digits, and then have 0.123456781 and 0.123456782).
Then I create an object that has the values as names and the second axis as values, eg: `axis_map = {"0.123456781": "Teen", "0.123456782": "Adult"}`, which I can then use in the creation of the tooltip.

```
// first axis
var tt = '<b>Axis 1</b>: ' + params[0].name + '<br>'; 

// second axis
let y2 = axis_map[(params[0].value).toFixed(8)];
tt += '<b>Axis 2</b>: ' + y2 + '<br>';

// values
for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
  let nn = params[i].seriesName;
  let entry = '';
  entry += '<div style = \"text-align: left;\">' + params[i].marker + nn + ': </div>';
  entry += '<div style = \"text-align: right;\">' + params[i].value).toFixed(8) + '</div>';
  tt += entry;
}
tt += '</div>'
return tt;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use one axis which combines both your axis values and hide it.

[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar1&code=G4QwTgBAJiAuIQLwQNoQgWAFDoN7QHsBbASwDsQzYAJSqALggHIAlEgcwAtYmAaCEOwCmjJgBUhQsnwigANgFcREALJxOAOjB1iACgCU_YWShCwogGJCiIOUKYQAvv0w4I-KMXKUadUWy4efkFlJgBBKAU5INlbJUY1WE1tEz1DCGNTc2YrGzsHZ3RsPEJSCipaE38ObhkQ_yFYEjAhKBl5eNV1LR0iAyMpLMtrW3snF2L3Uu8Kv2YAGSEAMxj65gkpdrjlROTe_ozBs2G8scLXEs8yn0qGBeXV4VEIqJiOne6Uq4PM45yR_LjIpuDxecq-Kr3FZ1J7MFiNZqtLaKD5JHqpPrpX7ZJi5UYFFwXKZXGYQu6sGqPUIbaT8d4JT77LFHHFqQHnSag66zSEUwIw0IvaLIzq7dHfZkmP5MNlnCYg6bg27VfnBWGsBEtNp07YMtFfNIDKWs_FAolc0nKqFU0Q0kWovYYn4s0SygnAy5gm5zJiLaFqwWRYU6lF6x0So1DZhus2cxXe3l-m1wzVIkOixlOyVRmWmjlYAC6AG5sNgCAAHJoEMhIdyTJqwOyMXCTdCwIQAD1glhAAGshBAAGrbADOECWBEgABEvVQILcBCYIGFhHxJs56wQCNESOXm62ILAwBxhDiQB2SCO1250BOwDZYO3sksFGQAMZVsi6cvgEBEEf6HWN7oBAb7ViO25CBocgEOw36_v--hFhAAD0KHjpO0BCAARgo7DsOQ7AQNWcgAJ4HugoCQLAW47uWtY_to_4oAADAWGgUEQA4ANTMAAPNhYAAHxMMhRIgRhkC6FREAkLWLHIXJfEQIxf4jtBUjsEkincdxgH4OJEmHrRTT0dxyCqcxJDsTYYD9pAvGWSOKDWRoI5mCQQgjgAcn-PHMKIECOQhzmue8Gg0RYJAdq0ugAEyAbxTACcJokekZjjpRJLSwAoYA1jR26mWJB6OOuvCTHYmT7sBMDwIwKC4gC9j8AARLKrUFuVkwdmEF4jg1B4GRRh6keWoRvnAQjsJOpEyIZ6AjpwBAAO6MEeSgVcB6B1SADV8rU_C-g8MgHTEx3-nClKnUmTAFvKRkCP18wgNhQhyM2WVGeQT7yIwLEPY9EBgAQ8Dtv9gMSfmUOQ1MC2jeNoiTe2M1gHNW2PUtq2MEstjuRjRm7ftATcBAdpHUmZOSLSV2BMuQbnZTQrnSTsAQPCTRajdDzs6mbT3V96DnpeL1vR9cMjegP1mH9EAA4LIEg2Dyjy_DG7AerEnDdtCMTVNqPowrROoOI1Onczp0c4i_Ow0Lz2ve9n3w1LVAy7YEMK-gStTR7au2ypBAjiQn6iNhoM0UQ80jQQSxLO53YQAAzKrpUE_dkykX1l6DcBLY67AY2hO8TClZM6duO5x5eTnWsjZxoR4vkBMSQXiPMNh4DXo9vX9QAklKHaMAAjM3IHG7tGhLCQ0RmLoL7vp-ujB9Y-k5XlNbL0QGjYkgiDIE1pyiY4-gaDY5Zz6-H4kNWS_tkQq-NOvsl3xo7xFsfqdDXXfmuvio9toXUOnd_4QB7pefuphB4QBHiNY20A4AgEntPJ8F8F7Xy_JvB-uV8rP2sNvFku995unfifM-qCr430we4NeODN6v22CQ0ubgupYEcEWIAA):

```js
var data = [  
  { dominantHand: 'Right', age: 'Teen', value: Math.random(), gender: 'Female' },  
  { dominantHand: 'Right', age: 'Adult', value: Math.random(), gender: 'Female' },  
  { dominantHand: 'Right', age: 'Retired', value: Math.random(), gender: 'Female' },  
  { dominantHand: 'Left', age: 'Teen', value: Math.random(), gender: 'Female' },  
  { dominantHand: 'Left', age: 'Adult', value: Math.random(), gender: 'Female' },  
  { dominantHand: 'Left', age: 'Retired', value: Math.random(), gender: 'Female' },   
  { dominantHand: 'Right', age: 'Teen', value: Math.random(), gender: 'Male' },  
  { dominantHand: 'Right', age: 'Adult', value: Math.random(), gender: 'Male' },  
  { dominantHand: 'Right', age: 'Retired', value: Math.random(), gender: 'Male' },  
  { dominantHand: 'Left', age: 'Teen', value: Math.random(), gender: 'Male' },  
  { dominantHand: 'Left', age: 'Adult', value: Math.random(), gender: 'Male' },  
  { dominantHand: 'Left', age: 'Retired', value: Math.random(), gender: 'Male' },  
];

option = {
  title: {
    text: 'Fake Values for Dominant Hand and Age',
  },
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    formatter: function(params) {
      console.log(params); // for debugging only
      var tooltip = params[0].name + '<br>';  
      for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {  
        tooltip += params[i].marker + params[i].seriesName + ': ' + params[i].value.toFixed(2) + '<br>';  
      }  
      return tooltip;  
    }
  },
  legend: {
    data: ['Female', "Male"]
  },
  xAxis: [
    {  
      type: 'category',  
      show: true,
      data: ['Right', 'Left', 'Right', 'Left', 'Right', 'Left'],  
      axisLabel: {  
        interval: 0,  
        rotate: 0,  
      },  
    },  
    {  
      type: 'category',
      show: false,
      data: ['Right Teen', 'Left Teen', 'Right Adult', 'Left Adult', 'Right Retired', 'Left Retired'],  
      axisLabel: {  
        interval: 0,  
        rotate: 0,  
      },
    },
    {  
      type: 'category',  
      data: ['Teen', 'Adult', 'Retired'],  
      axisLabel: {  
        interval: 0,  
        rotate: 0,  
      },  
      position: 'bottom',  
      offset: 30,  
    },
  ],
  yAxis: [
    {
      type: 'value'
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Female',
      type: 'bar',
      xAxisIndex: 1,
      data: data.filter(function(item) {return item.gender === 'Female';}).map(function(item) {return item.value;})
    },
    {
      name: 'Male',
      type: 'bar',
      xAxisIndex: 1,
      data:  data.filter(function(item) {return item.gender === 'Male';}).map(function(item) {return item.value;})
    }
  ]
};
```